# Allocating UIDatePicker in a background thread?

Tags: uidatepicker

I am trying to allocate a UIDatePicker in a separate thread (performance gains for an iPhone 4), and for some reason the following code draws a black frame (where the date picker is supposed to go), and after about 20-30 seconds the date picker is shown.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;


    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, ^{
        self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.deviceRect.size.width, self.datePicker.frame.size.height)];
        [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(didSelectDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];
    });

});
```

I know the threading code works because I added a lengthy process and added a UIView when it was finished and everything shows up as expected. The reason I want to do this is because on an iPhone 4 the UIDatePicker lags when being displayed for the first time. You can see this by going to the Apple Calendar app and adding a date, there is noticeable delay before displaying the UIDatePicker.